# Compare user input values with the values stored in dictionaries in list in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am taking a value from user input and performing a check if its present in a list-dictionary database. The values with which i am comparing in dictionary items is stored in the list. But I am not able to perform any action if the value entered by the user matches with that stored in the database. Here is my code:

```
userDetails = []
# dateOfBith=['1992-09-01','1995-04-04','1993-04-06']
# datetimeparse = datetime.strptime(dateOfBith,'%dd-%mm-%yyyy')
# dateparse = datetime.datetime.strptime(dateOfBith, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%d-%m-%y')
accountDetails = [
    {"FirtsName": "JOHN", "LastName": "DENIS", "Account Number": "432524352345234", "Account Balance": "50000"},
    {"FirtsName": "AKASH", "LastName": "MAHAJAN", "Account Number": "432524352345234", "Account Balance": "50000"},
    {"FirtsName": "AMAN", "LastName": "RANA", "Account Number": "432524352345234", "Account Balance": "50000"},
    {"FirtsName": "ANKUR", "LastName": "JAIN", "Account Number": "432524352345234", "Account Balance": "50000"},
]

for x in accountDetails:
    print (x["FirtsName"], x["LastName"], x["Account Number"], x["Account Number"])
specialCharacters = re.compile('[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]')

firstName = str(input("Enter First Name"))
FIRSTNAME = firstName.upper()
while FIRSTNAME == "" or FIRSTNAME.isdigit() or specialCharacters.search(FIRSTNAME) != None:
    print("The account does not exist with the given details,Enter valid First name")
    firstName = str(input("Enter First Name"))
    FIRSTNAME = firstName.upper()

while FIRSTNAME:
    for x in accountDetails:
        usersFirstName = x["FirtsName"]
        print(usersFirstName)

    for j in usersFirstName:
         FIRSTNAME != j:
            print("The account does not exist with the given details,Enter valid First name")
            firstName = str(input("Enter First Name"))
            userDetails = firstName.upper()

        else:
            userDetails.append(FIRSTNAME)
        lastName = str(input("Enter Last Name"))
```

Comment: Note: this solution has O(n) complexity, only advisable for one isolated lookup. I suggest, as in my answer, you restructure your input for O(1) complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic seems overcomplicated. My advice is to restructure your dictionary, possibly using `collections.defaultdict`. Then just query your new dictionary. This means you can take advantage of O(1) lookup complexity as opposed to O(n) for each query.

```
from collections import defaultdict

# restructure as nested dictionary
d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))
for item in accountDetails:
    d[item['FirtsName']][item['LastName']] = item

# get valid first name
while True:
    first_name_input = input('Enter First Name:\n').upper()
    if first_name_input in d:
        break
    else:
        print('Enter valid First Name')

# get valid last name
while True:
    last_name_input = input('Enter Last Name:\n').upper()
    if last_name_input in d[first_name_input]:
        break
    else:
        print('Enter valid Last Name')

print(d[first_name_input][last_name_input])
```

For duplicate first & last name combinations, you can use a nested `defaultdict` with values as `list` instead of `dict`.

**Example**

```
Enter First Name:
JOHN
Enter Last Name:
DENIS
{'FirtsName': 'JOHN', 'LastName': 'DENIS', 'Account Number': '432524352345234', 'Account Balance': '50000'}
```

Comment: And the tried to verify it-while True:
    dob_input = input('Enter dob:\n')
    if  dob_input in d[first_name_input]:
        break
    else:
        print('Enter valid dob')


print(d[first_name_input][last_name_input])

Comment: But date of birth can't be validated, Can you help me out with this, I am new to python.

Comment: @RohnKerry, I'm not sure what you mean by validation. And date of birth isn't in your input data. I suggest you ask a new question if still stuck.

Comment: I am taking user input as -01-05-1993

Comment: Please try: [Ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with a [mcve].

Comment: Validation means to verify if the user has entered the correct date of birth as stored in dictionary database.

Comment: What if I have to print only account number and account balance from dictionary after verification?

Comment: Change this line to a dictionary comprehension: `d[item['FirtsName']][item['LastName']] = item`. I suggestion you search on SO. If you're still stuck after a few hours, feel free to ask as a separate question.

Comment: By SO you mean search operation or Sorting?

Comment: No, I mean StackOverflow.

Comment: Ok thanks, Can you tell me what if I have to print only account number and account balance from dictionary after verification from this solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
def isDuplicate(value, fieldName, database):
    for entry in database:
        if fieldName in entry and entry[fieldName] == value:
            return True

    return False
```

This function will check to see if the input exists in any of the entry's in your database list as the fieldName desired. An example to check if JOHN appears as a first name would be..

```
isDuplicate("JOHN", "FirstName", accountDetails)
```